# How to retrieve hierarchical data stored in mysql using sql-query

Tags: mysql

My Database structure is like follows

```
id category    parent
-------------------------
1  Programming 
2  Database    Programming
3  MySQL       Database
```

Now when i query for MySQL, i should get the result as

```
MySQL -> Database -> Programming
```

I received some suggestions that, i can do it using Stored Procedures. But it will make my query slow.

Comment: see this: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: +1 for representation & very innocent question...

Comment: thanks Omesh & Waasim...

Comment: Omesh, your link was much helpful. It solved my purpose for now. But when the application grows, the number of category grows, it may slow down my query because for each depth, i need a join.

Comment: Omesh, you provided me something which i exactly wanted

Answer (score 1):

This is just what `JOIN`s are made for.

Answer (score 0):

means you want to display output

Database -> Programming

this format.

I tried one query

```
 select category,"->",parent from table where id =2;
```

it gave output

```
category ->  parent
Database -> Programming
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, But i need it further. The output should be MySQL -> Database -> Programming (instead of MySQL -> Database)

Comment: try this one   select "MySQL","->",category,"->",parent from table where id =2;

Answer (score 0):

Check this query and let me know if it works or not( testtube is my table name )---

```
SELECT a.category,  "->", a.parent,  "->", b.parent
FROM testtube AS a
INNER JOIN testtube AS b
WHERE a.parent = b.category
AND a.category =  "MySql"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```